# Error with Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrive usernames from Parse's Server with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. I want the results to be stored inside a NSArray, but I get an error in the code. 
Here's it:

```
let query: PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
    query.orderByAscending("username")
    query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: myUserId as! String)

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects:NSArray?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

    }
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSArray?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type 'PFQueryArrayResultBlock?'

I know that everything is working when changing 'NSArray?' to '[PFObject]?', but I want to result to be an Array.. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following:
declare this:

```
var array:NSArray = NSArray()


query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

if error != nil {
print("error")
} else {
if let objects = objects{
for object in objects {

self.append(object)

}

}

}


    }
```

Comment: I have a NSMutableArray called 'chatMatesArray'. I want the app to store usernames in that NSMutableArray, but that has not a .append function. Just a .addObject one that can't work with PFObject.

Comment: Sorry, was just writing some random code in java. Try to convert PFObject to an AnyObject. and then addObject / addElement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the conversion in the callback parameters. Your callback needs to respect the type that will be supplied and then your code in the callback can mutate the supplied parameters and store them.